# Pseudocode to Python 2.7 Multiple Errors

Tags: python, python-2.7, pseudocode

I am currently working a homework assignment and can not understand what I am doing wrong in my code conversion. I am having multiple issues, which are described under the code that I have. The assigned question and pseudocode are below:

```
>Write python code for the following Burger Joint:
>•  Your menu items only include the following food with accompanied price: 
>o  Yum Yum Burger = .99
>o  Grease Yum Fries = .79
>o  Soda Yum = 1.09
>•  Allow the user of the program to purchase any quantity of these items on one order. 
>•  Allow the user of the program to purchase one or more types of these items on one >order.
>•  After the order is placed, calculate total and add a 6% sales tax. 
>•  Print to the screen a receipt showing the total purchase price.
```

**Here is the pseudocode:**

```
Module main()

Call declareVariables(endProgram, endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal, option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount)

//Loop to run program again
While endProgram == “no”

    Call resetVariables(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal)     
    //Loop to take in order
    While endOrder == “no”
        Display “Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger”
        Display “Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries”
        Display “Enter 3 for Soda Yum”
        Input option
        If option == 1 Then
            Call getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)
        Else If option == 2 Then
            Call getFry(totalFry, fryCount)
        Else If option == 3 Then
            Call getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount)
        End If

Display “Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items: )”
Input endOrder
    End While

Call calcTotal(burgerTotal, fryTotal, sodaTotal, total, subtotal, tax)
Call printReceipt(total)

Display “Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order)”
Input endProgram
End While

End Module

Module declareVariables(String Ref endProgram, String Ref endOrder, Real Ref totalBurger, Real Ref totalFry, Real Ref totalSoda, Real Ref  total, Real Ref tax, Real Ref subtotal, Real Ref option, Real Ref burgerCount, Real Ref fryCount, Real Ref sodaCount)
Declare String endProgram = “no”
Declare String endOrder = “no”
Declare Real totalBurger = 0
Declare Real totalFry = 0
Declare Real totalSoda = 0
Declare Real total = 0
Declare Real tax = 0
Declare Real subtotal = 0
Declare Integer option = 0
Declare Integer burgerCount = 0
Declare Integer fryCount = 0
Declare Integer sodaCount = 0
End Module

Module resetVariables (Real Ref totalBurger, Real Ref totalFry, Real Ref totalSoda, Real Ref total, Real Ref tax, Real Ref subtotal)

//reset variables
totalBurger = 0
totalFry = 0
totalSoda = 0
total = 0
tax = 0
subtotal = 0
End Module

Module getBurger(Real Ref totalBurger, Integer burgerCount)
Display “Enter the number of burgers you want”
Input burgerCount   
Set totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount * .99
End Module

Module getFry(Real Ref totalFry, Integer fryCount)
Display “Enter the number of fries you want”
Input fryCount  
Set totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79
End Module

Module getSoda(Real Ref totalSoda, Integer sodaCount)
Display “Enter the number of sodas you want”
Input sodaCount 
Set totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09
End Module

Module calcTotal(Real totalBurger, Real totalFry, Real totalSoda, Real Ref total, Real subtotal, Real tax)
Set subtotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
Set tax = subtotal * .06
Set total = subtotal + tax
End Module

Module printReceipt(Real total)
Display “Your total is $”, total
End Module
```

**Here is the python code I have so far (python 2.7):**

```
def main():

    declareVariables(endProgram, endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal, option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount)

    ##Loop to run program again
    while endProgram == "no":
        resetVariables(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal)


        ##Loop to take in order
        while endOrder == "no":
            print "Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger"
            print "Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries"
            print "Enter 3 for Soda Yum"
            option = input("Enter Now: ")
            if option == 1:
                getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)
            elif option == 2:
                getFry(totalFry, fryCount)
            elif option == 3:
                getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount)
            endOrder = raw_input ("Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items): ")
        calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)
        printReceipt(total)

        endProgram = raw_input("Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order)")

def declareVariables(endProgram, endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal, option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount):
    endProgram = "no"
    endOrder = "no"
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFry = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0
    tax = 0
    subtotal = 0
    option = 0
    burgerCount = 0
    fryCount = 0
    sodaCount = 0

def resetVariables(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal):
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFry = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0
    tax = 0
    subtotal = 0



def getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount):
    burgerCount = input ("Enter the number of burgers you want: ")
    totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount *.99
    return totalBurger


def getFry(totalFry, fryCount):
    fryCount = input ("Enter the number of fries you want: ")
    totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79
    return totalFry


def getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount):
    sodaCount = input ("Enter the number of sodas you want: ")
    totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09
    return totalSoda


def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax):
    subtotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
    tax = subtotal * .06
    total = subtotal + tax
    return total


def printReceipt(total):
    print "Your total is $", total

main()
```

**These are the issues I can not figure out how to work past:**

1. Local variable endProgram referenced before assignment. This is the first time I have seen variable initialization called from a module. The module is called at the beginning so it looks like they should be all initialized. What am I missing with this?
2. If I comment out the declarevariable modules and just create globals with manual assignments, the code will run, but it always returns a receipt total of $0, as if the parameters aren't being passed  by reference. Not sure how to make it accept the reference in the module.

Can someone please assist with pointing me in the right direction? I feel like I am really close and just overlooking something really simple.

**Note:** I did a search on google and the forums, and have actually found this exact problem in other locations. However, the professor has constructed the pseudocode instead of allowing us to do so in this example. I think I would have solved this a bit differently, but the python code must match the professors pseudo for me to receive credit.

Thank you for any assistance you can offer.

**Edit:
Thank you for the pointers. I changed the code to the following, but I am still getting $0 for receipt totals when I run the edited code. Any direction on that part of it?**

```
def main():

    endProgram = "no"
    endOrder = "no"
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFry = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0
    tax = 0
    subtotal = 0
    option = 0
    burgerCount = 0
    fryCount = 0
    sodaCount = 0

    ##Loop to run program again
    while endProgram == "no":


        ##Loop to take in order
        while endOrder == "no":
            print "Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger"
            print "Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries"
            print "Enter 3 for Soda Yum"
            option = input("Enter Now: ")
            if option == 1:
                getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)
            elif option == 2:
                getFry(totalFry, fryCount)
            elif option == 3:
                getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount)
            endOrder = raw_input ("Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items): ")
        calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)
        printReceipt(total)

        endProgram = raw_input("Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order)")



def getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount):
    burgerCount = input ("Enter the number of burgers you want: ")
    totalBurger = totalBurger + burgerCount *.99
    return totalBurger


def getFry(totalFry, fryCount):
    fryCount = input ("Enter the number of fries you want: ")
    totalFry = totalFry + fryCount * .79
    return totalFry


def getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount):
    sodaCount = input ("Enter the number of sodas you want: ")
    totalSoda = totalSoda + sodaCount * 1.09
    return totalSoda


def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax):
    subtotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
    tax = subtotal * .06
    total = subtotal + tax
    return total


def printReceipt(total):
    print "Your total is $", total

main()
```

**Final Edit:**

**In case anyone else was interested, this is how I was instructed to complete the assignment per the professor. Thank you all for your help.**

```
def main():

    ## Initialize Variables

    endProgram, endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal, option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount = declareVariables()


    ##Loop to run program again
    while endProgram == "no":

        #Reset variables
        endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal = resetVariables()

        ##Loop to take in order
        while endOrder == "no":
            print "Enter 1 for Yum Yum Burger"
            print "Enter 2 for Grease Yum Fries"
            print "Enter 3 for Soda Yum"
            option = input("Enter Now: ")
            if option == 1:
                totalBurger = getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)
            elif option == 2:
                totalFry = getFry(totalFry, fryCount)
            elif option == 3:
                totalSoda = getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount)
            endOrder = raw_input ("Do you want to end your order? (Enter no to add more items): ")
        total = calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax)
        printReceipt(total)
        endProgram = raw_input("Do you want to end the program? (Enter no to process a new order)")


## Calculate the total cost of burgers and return totalBurger
def getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount):
    burgerCount = input ("Enter the number of burgers you want: ")
    totalBurger = totalBurger + ( burgerCount *.99 )
    return totalBurger

## Calculate the total cost of fries and return totalFry
def getFry(totalFry, fryCount):
    fryCount = input ("Enter the number of fries you want: ")
    totalFry = totalFry + ( fryCount * .79 )
    return totalFry

## Calculate the total cost of soda and return totalSoda
def getSoda(totalSoda, sodaCount):
    sodaCount = input ("Enter the number of sodas you want: ")
    totalSoda = totalSoda + ( sodaCount * 1.09 )
    return totalSoda

## Calculate the total cost of burgers, fries, & soda. Add tax and returns the total. 
def calcTotal(totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, subtotal, tax):
    subtotal = totalBurger + totalFry + totalSoda
    tax = subtotal * .06
    total = subtotal + tax
    return total

## Print the receipt for the total cost.
def printReceipt(total):
    print "Your total is $", total

## Initialize all of the variables and return all of them
def declareVariables():

     endProgram = "no"
     endOrder = "no"
     totalBurger = 0
     totalFry = 0
     totalSoda = 0
     total = 0
     tax = 0
     subtotal = 0
     option = 0
     burgerCount = 0
     fryCount = 0
     sodaCount = 0

     return endProgram, endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal, option, burgerCount, fryCount, sodaCount

## Reset the variables for when the order ends but program continues to start a new order.
## Return all of the reset variables
def resetVariables():

    endOrder = "no"
    totalBurger = 0
    totalFry = 0
    totalSoda = 0
    total = 0
    tax = 0
    subtotal = 0

    return endOrder, totalBurger, totalFry, totalSoda, total, tax, subtotal


main()
```

Comment: This may help you: http://gettingstartedwithpython.blogspot.com/2012/05/variable-scope.html

Comment: You can not stay 100 % close to the pseudo code and make this code work. Regarding e.g. `declareVariables(...)`: it does not make sense in Python to actually call a function here. You *could* do this, but in my opinion the better approach just for this exercise would be to declare these variables in the global scope, and then modify them later (using the `global` keyword, if required).

Comment: The pseudocode you have been provided with is not sensible from a Python perspective; are you sure you're using the correct language? For example, `declareVariables` would create local variables within the function, then abandon them when it ends.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I changed the code to the following, but still not sure why I am getting a return of $0.00 when I enter in the order. Any help on that part?

Comment: You never add to the total when calling "getX" functions. Try `total += getSoda(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Declare the functions/variables you intend to use before you use them.**

Put the definitions of all your methods **before** `main` where you call them. For example, your `main` doesn't know what the function `declareVariables` is while it executes, hence, the exception.

**2. Global variables or return variables**

Variables by reference doesn't work like C/++. You might want to look at [this](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types).
You can either `return` the variables you've changed or declare them as `global` (which might be easiest). You can find more info [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement)

A side note, variables don't actually hold data but are more like labels. So `a = b` is copying labels to the same object. You can try this out yourself:

```
>>a = [1,2,3]
>>b = a  # This isn't copying values, but labels
>>b.append(100)  # Changing value of 'b' would change the underlying object, thereby changing all referenced objects
>>print a
[1, 2, 3, 100]
```

Comment: If you're going to provide examples, they ought to be something that works. Assignments in Python do not work they way you describe `In [1]: a = 1
In [2]: b = a
In [3]: b = 5
In [4]: a
Out[4]: 1`

Comment: @mogambo Thank you sir. If I return to the variable that I am trying to call like I did in the edited code, shouldn't that do what you are stating in part 2? That was the goal, just not sure it is functioning correctly.

Comment: Yes, but when you call, for example `getBurger` you don't store the returned value. Calculate the `total` from the returned values, like `total += getBurger(totalBurger, burgerCount)` etc. If you want to use `calcTotal` you should use `global` variables (See the link in the answer).

Comment: @vartec: Oops! Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed the example :)